# Cannot extract data from an HTTP PUT request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, http, curl, put

I am trying to implement a simple server in Ruby, but somehow I can't get the data from a put request.

curl request that I am making:

```
curl -v -X PUT localhost:2016/api/kill -d {"connId" : 1}
```

The server seems to be reading the request alright.
The code:

```
  while line = socket.gets
    puts line.chomp
    request << line.chomp
    break if line =~ /^\s*$/
  end
```

produces the output:

```
PUT /api/kill HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: localhost:2016
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But I don't see the data anywhere?

Am I supposed to see it?

Is something wrong with the curl request?

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around the body.

```
curl -v -X PUT localhost:2016/api/kill -d '{"connId" : 1}'
```

Comment: Worked with a minor modification! Thank You!

Comment: Had to read content-length number of bytes after the loop. Worked!